# Rest Call using shell returning 500 error

Tags: bash, shell, rest, curl

Rest Call using shell returning 500 error but when I am printing the command that I want to run,its executing perfectly when I am tried to run in bash

```
TEST="curl -X PUT $urlvalue -X PUT -i -H "$headervalue1" -H "$headervalue2" -c cookies.txt -d '${datavalue//\'/\'}'"
echo $TEST
RESPONSE=`$TEST`
echo $RESPONSE
```

Output for test is as below

```
curl -X PUT http://abcxyz/metadata -X PUT -i -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -c cookies.txt -d '{"fileName":"ABC_GB.zip"}'
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 times `-X PUT` ? Try adding `-v` and edit your post with the output

Comment: As per your question I have used the PUT only before the url now. Still its not working. But the TEST output when put in bash shell its working though

 curl -X PUT http://abcxyz/metadata -i -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -c cookies.txt -d '{"fileName":"ABC_GB.zip"}'

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a quote issue, try better this (and you have 2 times `-X`, it's redundant) :

```
TEST="curl -i -X PUT \"$urlvalue\" -H \"$headervalue1\" -H \"$headervalue2\" -c cookies.txt -d \"${datavalue//\'/\'}\""
```

Or with a function:

```
put_stuff() {
    curl -i -X PUT "$1" -H "$2" -H "$3" -c cookies.txt -d "${datavalue//\'/\'}"
}
```

Usage :

```
put_stuff "$urlvalue" "$headervalue1" "$headervalue2"
```

### Explanations :

In shell, you can't have nested double quotes, there's a conflict:

"Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words